# Can Honeywell c wire adapter or Venstar add-a-wire work with dual transformer system?

Tags: wiring, thermostat

I have a dual transformer system where the baseboard heat (RH-W) and AC (RC-Y-G) are wired independently and currently it's working well on my Honeywell thermostat. I would like to buy a smart thermostat, it can be Honeywell T5, Ecobee or Nest.  I would like to keep the fan running independently which means not jumping the G and Y terminals, I saw that Venstar add-a-wire or Honeywell C wire adapter or Ecobee Power adapter kit might help, but there is no information on the web about wiring them for a dual transformer system.

My AC has only 3 wires and I can't run a new wire due to the location of the furnace and the thermostat without tearing down a wall and ceiling.

Any advice?

Comment: Don't be so confident that a new thermostat wire will require demolition - there are tricks in the wiring retrofit trade that can often avoid it. Anyway, tell us more about the equipment: is there central heat too, or only baseboard heat and central air conditioning? Attach photos of the existing wiring and the equipment diagrams if possible.

Comment: Can you post photos of the existing wiring at the air handler as well as the air handler's wiring diagram?